# Property Update function for properties inside a collection

Tags: python, properties

I have a PropertyGroup Class called PPP, like the Collection Example on this page: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_63_release/bpy.props.html

The problem is that one of the properties in the PPP class, pfloat calls an update function "update_func"

I need to be able to tell which ppp has been changed when the update_func is called, normally you would use self to determine it but that does not seem to work it just returns: `PPP("")`

Any Ideas / what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Described behavior couldn't confirmed, see [T39798](https://developer.blender.org/T39798).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution to this problem using Python Lambda.

Create an an update function called "updateID" with inputs for Self,Context and ID

then when creating your property do this:

`update = eval("lambda s,c: updateID(s,c,\"%s\")" %foo)`

foo is the unique ID that you use to identify that object inside the updateID function like the properties name.

This will create a unique update function for each instance of the property that simply calls the "updateID" function and plums in the ID variable.

Comment: I'm certain you could drop the eval in the code i.e. `update = lambda s,c: updateID(s,c,"{0}".format(foo))` or `update = lambda s,c: updateID(s,c,foo)`

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I can't tell whether it's a known limitation or bug, but it definately returns the reference to the CollectionProperty only.</strike>

You need a concept of one element in the collection being "active", e.g. have an `IntProperty` alongside and use it for a `template_list()` for instance. Then use that number to get the right item:

```
self[context.scene.ppp_index].pfloat = 1.23
```

There's actually a reference to the CollectionProperty **item** returned,
see https://developer.blender.org/T39798

Comment: Thank you for the help.
I have experimented with using Lambda it create the update_func If i can get that to work I might post it as an answer.
Otherwise I will mark this as correct if I get no better answers or make no progress.

Comment: You should contact the python module owners and ask if a property callback in a collection is supposed to get the collection or the property passed, maybe no one thought of it?

Comment: Posted bug report and waiting for developer feedback: https://developer.blender.org/T39798

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I am not very good with python/Blender. I was not comfortable with giving enough information about the problem.